# Re-using mpfr_t in long chain of arithmetic operations

Tags: c++, gmp, mpfr

I'm writing a function which uses mpfr_t as its main data type. In this function, there will be long chains of operations which need temporary variables to store intermediate results. I'd like to minimize the number of temporary variables I'll need, so I'm doing something like this:

```
mpfr_t tmp1;
mpfr_t tmp2;
mpfr_sub(tmp1, a, b, MPFR_RNDN);
mpfr_mul(tmp2, c, d, MPFR_RNDN);
mpfr_add(tmp2, tmp1, a, MPFR_RNDN);
```

Then later in the function:

```
mpfr_mul(tmp1, e, f, MPFR_RNDN);
```

Can I rely on the prior value of tmp1 being completely cleared from the variable when it is reassigned with `e*f`?

Comment: Yes, just like when you write z=x*y the previous value of z disappears.

Comment: I know that's the case for standard C/++ arithmetic, but is it also true for MPFR?

Comment: Yes (I already said that). What else would you expect?

Comment: Nothing in particular, but in my experience the problems that really bite you in the ass are the ones you *don't* expect.